# Output changes after returning value to main! (please give a simple fix)

Tags: c, algorithm, return

This is a program to print the largest element in a n(power of 2) sized array. The output is correct when i print inside the function but it changes when i return value to the main.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define max(x,y) (((int)((x)<(y)) * (y)) + ((int)((y)<=(x)) * (x)))

    int compare(int *arr,int sze){
        static int i ;
        int nsize = sze/2;
        int arr2[nsize];
        for(i = 0; i < sze ; i += 2){
            int x = max(*(arr + i),*(arr + i + 1));
            printf("%d\n",x );
            arr2[i/2] = x;
        }
        if(nsize == 1){

            int t = arr2[0];
            printf("abc%d\n", t );   //correct output
            return t;                
        }
        printf("\n");
        compare(arr2,nsize);
    }

    void main(){
        int size = 8;
        int arr[8] = {12,14,54,76,87,89,45,34};
        int maximum = compare(arr,size);
        printf("Maximum value in the array is %d\n", maximum ); //wrong output
    }
```

Output is:

```
    14
    76
    89
    45

    76
    89

    89
    abc89
    Maximum value in the array is 4195472
```

Comment: you're not returning anything in the last line of `compare`

Comment: ...which would very likely have been flagged as a warning if you cranked up your compiler warnings to pedantic levels.

Answer (score 3):

You do not return the value to main, and so have an undefined behaviour while using the "return value", e.g. the last line of `compare` should be:

```
return compare(arr2,nsize);
```

Comment: will this not cause a problem in the logic of the program?

Comment: It will fix the implementation. Right now the problem is that you want to do recursive calls, but the fact that you don't return the value you got from the recursive call means your implementation is broken (and this is why you asked in the first place)

Comment: yeah i finally understood what is causing the problem!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a warning that points right at the problem.

```
$ cc -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
test.c:22:5: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
```

"control may reach end of non-void function" means you're missing a `return`. In this case when you recurse at the end of `compare`.

Some languages, like Perl and Javascript, if there is no `return` will return the "last evaluated expression". C won't do that. The behavior is "undefined" which means you'll get 0 or garbage or the program will crash.

Comment: please add the correction to the code!

Comment: @DivyanshJha Sorry, that's too much like writing the code for you. You should be able to figure it out from the answer. If not, please talk about what you don't understand and I'll help. If you're doing recursion, it's really important you understand `return`.

Comment: i am not able to understand the how return is causing a problem here! When it prints 89 the last time it should return t and get out of that function! then whats the problem!! why value of maximum is wrong in main?